# Why Typescript infers any when using bracket notation

Tags: typescript

When using bracket notation for Non-existent property, Typescript infers any.
On the other hand, when using dot notation, compile error occurs(I extected.)

```
type Hoge = {
    id: number
    name: string
}

const func = (value: Hoge) => {
    const a = value['code'] // a is any
    const b = value.code // Property 'code' does not exist on type 'Hoge'.
}
```

Why does Typescript infer any when using bracket notation for Non-existent property ?

※noImplicitAny is false.

Comment: Because noImplicitAny is off. Turn it on so it's forbidden.